# Linear mixed model confidence intervals question

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, confidence-interval, emmeans

Hoping that you can clear some confusion in my head.

Linear mixed model is constructed  with `lmerTest`:

```r
MODEL <- lmer(Ca content ~ SYSTEM +(1 | YEAR/replicate) + 
               (1 | YEAR:SYSTEM), data = IOSDV1)
```

Fun starts happening when I'm trying to get the confidence intervals for the specific levels of the main effect.

Commands `emmeans` and `lsmeans` produce the same intervals (example; `SYSTEM A3: 23.9-128.9, mean 76.4, SE:8.96`).

However, the command `as.data.frame(effect("SYSTEM", MODEL))` produces different, narrower confidence intervals (example; `SYSTEM A3: 58.0-94.9, mean 76.4, SE:8.96`).

What am I missing and what number should I report?

To summarize, for the content of Ca, i have 6 total measurements per treatment (three per year, each from different replication).  I will leave the names in the code in my language, as used. Idea is to test if certain production practices affect the content of specific minerals in the grains. Random effects without residual variance were left in the model for this example.

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: CA ~ SISTEM + (1 | LETO/ponovitev) + (1 | LETO:SISTEM)
   Data: IOSDV1

REML criterion at convergence: 202.1

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.60767 -0.74339  0.04665  0.73152  1.50519 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 LETO:SISTEM    (Intercept)   0.0     0.0    
 ponovitev:LETO (Intercept)   0.0     0.0    
 LETO           (Intercept) 120.9    11.0    
 Residual                   118.7    10.9    
Number of obs: 30, groups:  LETO:SISTEM, 10; ponovitev:LETO, 8; LETO, 2

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)      76.417      8.959   1.548   8.530   0.0276 *
SISTEM[T.C0]     -5.183      6.291  24.000  -0.824   0.4181  
SISTEM[T.C110]  -13.433      6.291  24.000  -2.135   0.0431 *
SISTEM[T.C165]   -7.617      6.291  24.000  -1.211   0.2378  
SISTEM[T.C55]   -10.883      6.291  24.000  -1.730   0.0965 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
             (Intr) SISTEM[T.C0 SISTEM[T.C11 SISTEM[T.C16
SISTEM[T.C0  -0.351                                      
SISTEM[T.C11 -0.351  0.500                               
SISTEM[T.C16 -0.351  0.500       0.500                   
SISTEM[T.C5  -0.351  0.500       0.500        0.500      
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

> ls_means(MODEL, ddf="Kenward-Roger")
Least Squares Means table:

           Estimate Std. Error  df t value    lower    upper Pr(>|t|)  
SISTEMA3    76.4167     8.9586 1.5  8.5299  23.9091 128.9243  0.02853 *
SISTEMC0    71.2333     8.9586 1.5  7.9514  18.7257 123.7409  0.03171 *
SISTEMC110  62.9833     8.9586 1.5  7.0305  10.4757 115.4909  0.03813 *
SISTEMC165  68.8000     8.9586 1.5  7.6797  16.2924 121.3076  0.03341 *
SISTEMC55   65.5333     8.9586 1.5  7.3151  13.0257 118.0409  0.03594 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

  Confidence level: 95%
  Degrees of freedom method: Kenward-Roger

> emmeans(MODEL, spec = c("SISTEM"))
 SISTEM emmean   SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 A3       76.4 8.96 1.53     23.9      129
 C0       71.2 8.96 1.53     18.7      124
 C110     63.0 8.96 1.53     10.5      115
 C165     68.8 8.96 1.53     16.3      121
 C55      65.5 8.96 1.53     13.0      118

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95

> as.data.frame(effect("SISTEM", MODEL))
  SISTEM      fit       se    lower    upper
1     A3 76.41667 8.958643 57.96600 94.86734
2     C0 71.23333 8.958643 52.78266 89.68400
3   C110 62.98333 8.958643 44.53266 81.43400
4   C165 68.80000 8.958643 50.34933 87.25067
5    C55 65.53333 8.958643 47.08266 83.98400
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi, Can you make your example more explicit please. Can you show exactly what code oyu call to get both confidence intervals and show both outputs.

Comment: And, what packages? Looks like you're using both the `effects` and the `emmeans` packages?  Can we have a [mre]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the dreaded "denominator degrees of freedom" question, i.e. what kind (if any) of finite-sample correction is being employed. **tl;dr** `emmeans` is using a Kenward-Roger correction, which is more or less the most accurate available option — the only reason *not* to use K-R is if you have a large data set for which it becomes unbearably slow.

### load packages, simulate data, fit model

```r
library(lmerTest)
library(emmeans)
library(effects)
dd <- expand.grid(f=factor(letters[1:3]),g=factor(1:20),rep=1:10)
set.seed(101)
dd$y <- simulate(~f+(1|g), newdata=dd, newparams=list(beta=rep(1,3),theta=1,sigma=1))[[1]]
m <- lmer(y~f+(1|g), data=dd)
```

### compare default emmeans with effects

```r
emmeans(m, ~f)
##  f emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
##  a  0.848 0.212 21.9    0.409     1.29
##  b  1.853 0.212 21.9    1.414     2.29
##  c  1.863 0.212 21.9    1.424     2.30

## Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
## Confidence level used: 0.95 

as.data.frame(effect("f",m))
##   f       fit        se     lower    upper
## 1 a 0.8480161 0.2117093 0.4322306 1.263802
## 2 b 1.8531805 0.2117093 1.4373950 2.268966
## 3 c 1.8632228 0.2117093 1.4474373 2.279008
```

`effects` doesn't explicitly tell us what/whether it's using a finite-sample correction: we could dig around in the documentation or the code to try to find out.  Alternatively, we can tell `emmeans` *not* to use finite-sample correction:

```r
emmeans(m, ~f, lmer.df="asymptotic")
##  f emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
##  a  0.848 0.212 Inf     0.433      1.26
##  b  1.853 0.212 Inf     1.438      2.27
##  c  1.863 0.212 Inf     1.448      2.28

## Degrees-of-freedom method: asymptotic 
## Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Testing shows that these are equivalent to about a tolerance of 0.001 (probably close enough). *In principle* we should be able to specify `KR=TRUE` to get `effects` to use Kenward-Roger correction, but I haven't been able to get that to work yet.

However, I will also say that there's something a little bit funky about your example. If we compute the distance between the mean and the lower CI in units of standard error, for `emmeans` we get `(76.4-23.9)/8.96 = 5.86`, which implies a *very* small effect degrees of freedom (e.g. about 1.55). That seems questionable to me unless your data set is extremely small ...

---

From your updated post, it appears that Kenward-Roger is indeed estimating only 1.5 denominator df.

In general it is dicey/not recommended to try fitting random effects where the grouping variable has a small number of levels (although see [here](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.04.11.439357v2) for a counterargument).  I would try treating `LETO` (which has only two levels) as a fixed effect, i.e.

```r
CA ~ SISTEM + LETO + (1 | LETO:ponovitev) + (1 | LETO:SISTEM)
```

and see if that helps.  (I would expect you would then get on the order of 7 df, which would make your CIs ± 2.4 SE instead of ± 6 SE ...)

Comment: Adding lmer.df="asymptotic" to the emmeans command produced identical results as with effect command. So this part is resolved. Thanks for that. Question remains, what data should i report? These infinite sample correction CI seem to be more in line of "expected" values, compared to very wide intervals with Kenward-Roger correction, that seem "funky". Regards. Aleš

Comment: Model was based on the assumption that YEAR (LETO) is by its nature a random factor with "uncontrollable" set of variables. If YEAR was to be fixed factor in the model, can the interaction between YEAR (LETO) and TREATMENT (SISTEM) be considered as a random factor in such circumstance? Or must i do interactions, similar as with factorial treatments?

Comment: This is turning into a [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) or `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org` question (i.e., more statistics than programming). There is a [section in the GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#should-i-treat-factor-xxx-as-fixed-or-random) on this topic. The problem is that treating year as a random effect implies that you think you can estimate the among-year variability, and generalize to unmeasured years, when you have only sampled years. (Arguably this is why you are getting such wide CIs.) ...

Comment: I would say that the model I provided (random effects of `ponovitev` and `SISTEM` nested within year) is reasonable.

Comment: Many thanks for the answers, i have the information that i needed. Regards,

Comment: If this answer solved your problem you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it ...

Comment: Ben, if possible, one additional question. Why am i getting in the fixed model also levels of the fixed model "SISTEM", suggesting a total of four fixed effect (btw, there are five levels of this variable). Is there something wrong in the coding or data preparation?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your question. You could check `unique(IOSDV1$SISTEM)`. For an `n`-level factor you will always get the first level characterized by the intercept and all others characterized by the difference from the intercept (unless you suppress the intercept with `-1` or use different contrasts); this is standard R behaviour.